# "Wegen" or "unter"?

Tags: grammar, preposition

What is the difference between "unter" and "wegen" when used in a sentence? In my dictionary one can either use "unter" or "wegen" with "müde":

> Ich war ***unter*** den Hausaufgaben sehr müde.
>
> Ich war ***wegen*** der Hausaufgaben sehr müde.

Do "unter" and "wegen" have different meanings in this context?

Comment: Your book is really really weird. May I ask when it was printed? In 1930? Seriously, I would not understand the sentence with "unter" to mean anything. It is just gibberish to me.

Comment: I forgot when it was printed but i can check. ;)

Comment: @Emanuel, [it makes total sense](http://www.123rf.com/photo_9410752_girl-student-with-books.html).

Comment: @Emanuel No matter when it was printed - I am sure there was never a rule like "You can/cannot use wegen/unter *with müde*." Most probably a misinterpretation of OP. Alas - *Unter großer geistiger Anspannung kann man leicht müde werden.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here "Unter" suggests something like "while doing". You wouldn't use it, when there is no time involved. You would most likely even say "ich war unter den Hausaufgaben sehr müde *geworden*" to stress the passing of time. "Unter" in this sense is uncommon in colloquial language.

Comment: I would actually say "über" in that context (Germany, Berlin) and I would not understand the version with "unter". The only temporal "unter" I know is "unter der Woche". Perhaps you could add where you come from beacuse I strongly believe that I am not the only one to say that.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, neither *unter* nor *wegen* are connected with *müde* in a way that the adjective would require any of these prepositions. You can replace the adjective with any word, and the sentence is equally fine or not fine, respectively:

> Ich war wegen der Hausaufgaben sehr langsam.
>   *Ich war unter den Hausaufgaben sehr langsam.

The reason for taking *unter* or *wegen* depends on something else. Let's take another example first:

> Ich leide unter Müdigkeit(=Ich bin sehr oft müde und das macht mir zu schaffen).

I would translate this sentence as *to suffer from tiredness*. In theory, you could also say *Ich leide wegen meiner Müdigkeit*. There is, however, a subtle difference. I'd translate that as *I suffer because of my tiredness*. But strictly speaking, it's at least very uncommon if not wrong. I didn't find any Google hits. But I found a few results for *Ich leider wegen meiner Größe*. Nevertheless, it's still more common to say *Ich leider unter meiner Größe*.
Anyway, *unter etwas leiden* is just a fixed expression and the actual definiton of *unter* isn't really applied. What I mean: you cannot translate it literally. So, you simply choose *unter* because of it being an expression and not because of the word *Müdigkeit*.

Back to your example: as already mentioned *wegen* means *because of*. So, you're saying:

> Because of my homework, I was tired.

First off, using *unter* would indicate a very different meaning. *Unter* means *during*, so while doing the homework. But the above sentence indicates that you're tired after you've finished your homework.
Whatever, *unter* doesn't work very well here. There's also a fixed expression *unter etwas sein*, as in *unter Druck sein*, or you can apply this literally, i.e. you are, for instance, below a surface.
But in your very example *unter* would be applied in the sense of *during*. When using *unter* in this meaning, it usually comes in collocation with *Woche* or *Tag*(-> *unter Tags* or *tagsunter*). Also take a look in *[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unter_darunter_abwaerts_tiefer#Bedeutung2a)*.
As you might realize, the phrase *unter der Woche* is quite generic. You don't refer to any specific time or action. In contrast, *unter den Hausaufgaben* would be very specific. So remember, you don't use *unter* when referring to a particular time frame or action. Again, this is how you would use *unter* in that sense:

> Unter der Woche bin ich *häufig* müde.

This sentences only says that you are often tired but not when and why exactly. It's not even sure, that you're tired every day.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is weird, but other sentences would work, e.g.:

> Ich war *unter* der Therapie sehr müde.
>
> Ich war *wegen* der Therapie sehr müde.

(I was so tired during the therapy.)

*unter etwas* is quite common in medical German.

Comment: german dictionaries should indicate in what field the prepositions are used.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33: they do: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unter_darunter_abwaerts_tiefer

Comment: Interestingly, I think your "unter"-example sentence sounds as weird as OPs example, but "Ich litt unter der Therapie" is fine.